# geom_dumbbell with coord_trans

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalt

I am trying to generate a dumbbell plot in ggplot, while also trying to log transform the x and y axes. System throws an error that I can't understand. Looking for some help.

Here is the sample code:

```
#create the data
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 100),
                 xend = c(2, 4, 6, 110),
                 y = c(1, 2, 3, 100)) 

#plot the untransformed dumbbell plot
library('ggalt')
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y)) + 
  geom_dumbbell()
```

[image]

```
#Try the plot with coordinate transformation
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y)) + 
  geom_dumbbell() + 
  coord_trans(x = 'log2', y = 'log2')
```

Throws error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , c("alpha", "colour", "size", "linetype")) :
> undefined columns selected

If I amend `coord_trans` so that `coord_trans(x = 'log2', xend = 'log2', y = 'log2)`, I get the error:

> Error in coord_trans(x = "log2", xend = "log2", y = "log2") :
> unused argument (xend = "log2")

What I want is the equivalent of this, with `geom_dumbbell()` rather than `geom_point()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_trans(x = 'log2', y = 'log2')
```

[image]

Any thoughts on how I can get geom_dumbbell() to work with coord_trans()?

Comment: This error is probably not the intended behaviour of the geom, so you might consider posting an issue on ggalt's github page to let the author know.

Comment: Makes sense. Posted the issue on github here: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt/issues/73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is weird, I don't know why it doesn't work with `geom_dumbbell`. I also didn't know that `geom_dumbbell` exists! So here is a hack I've been doing for years using `geom_linerange` and `geom_point` to build the components:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y = y)) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin=x, xmax=xend)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=xend)) +
  coord_trans(x = 'log2', y = 'log2')
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, the work around is effective for my problem.